# Classify as decidable, semi-decidable or not semi-decidable

Tags: computer-science, computability, automata, decidability

I have the set {p|∃y : Dom(ϕp) ⊆ Dom(ϕy)} and have to classify it as decidable, semi-decidable or not semi-decidable. I made a research and I found:

**Semi-Decidable**

If I have a word w ∈ L then a p program with input w stops and return "accept"

If I have a word w ∈/ L then a p program with input w don't stop or don't accept.

**Decidable**

If I have a word w ∈ L then a p program with input w stops and return "accept"

If I have a word w ∈/ L then a p program with input w stops and don't return "accept"

I didn't understand the relation between "classify" and my set, so I don't know how to classify it. I will preciate an explanation if possible.

Comment: Could you  explain what $Dom(\phi p)$ and $Dom(\phi y)$ mean?

Comment: Dom (φp) it's all the inputs that are accepted by a turing machine "p", and the same for Dom (φy). I think that it is semidecidable because not always i can choose y = p because it is a "exist". But im not sure about my proposal

Comment: "Y" wont contain always all the elements

Comment: So, what you mean is that there exists a turing machine y such that the set of inputs accepted by p is a subset of the inputs accepted by y?

Comment: yes, exactly as you said

Comment: If you are allowed to choose y = p, then the set consists of all Turing machines. So, any TM that accepts all of its inputs is a Decider for the set. That is a TM that takes as input another TM p and then accepts right away.

Comment: Then a good explanation will be: It is decidable because i always can choose p= y and then all turing machines will accept for this set, because a TM y can take input of the TM p and accepts.

Comment: Or you can say that a TM that ignores its input and accepts is a decider for the language since the language is simply the set of strings that represent encodings of TM's.

Answer (score 0):

Then a good explanation will be: It is decidable because I always can choose p = y and then all turing machines will accept for this set, because a TM y can take input of the TM p and accepts so the words that this set accepts will be Σ*.